# Why I can't put 2 dimensions in my Dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray

I would like to put dimensions for my variables with this list:
`['Time', 'Pressure', 'Temperature', 'Electrical conductivity', 'Salinity', 'Chlorophyll concentration']`.
So I tried to put a list for the dimensions but it doesn't work.

```
    ds = xr.Dataset(
        coords = coords,
        data_vars = {"hehe" : (('Time', 'Pres'), col_names_values2['c731'])},
        attrs = global_attributes
    )
```

When I execute my code, I get this:

```
ValueError: Could not convert tuple of form (dims, data[, attrs, encoding]): (('Time', 'Pres'), [55, 22]) to Variable.
```

On the other hand, when I put only one between the brackets, everything goes well:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (Time: 55, Pres: 55, Temp: 55, Cond: 55, Sal: 55,
              CHL: 55)
Coordinates:
  * Time     (Time) int32 55
  * Pres     (Pres) float64 55
  * Temp     (Temp) float64 55
  * Cond     (Cond) float64 55
  * Sal      (Sal) float64 55
  * CHL      (CHL) float64 55 
Data variables:
    hehe     (Time) float64 55
```

After all that, I tried to find an example on the xarray doc, so I tried what I found and it works! The problem is that I wrote exactly the same thing before, well in the same form and it doesn't work. Here is the code I found:

```
    ds = xr.Dataset(
        coords = coords,
        data_vars = {"foo": (("x", "y"), np.random.rand(4, 5))},
        attrs = global_attributes
    )
```

And here is the result :

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 4, y: 5, Time: 55, Pres: 55, Temp: 55, Cond: 55,
              Sal: 55, chl: 55)
Coordinates:
  * Time     (Time) 55
  * Pres     (Pres) 55
  * Temp     (Temp) 55
  * Cond     (Cond) 55
  * Sal      (Sal) 55
  * CHL      (CHL) 55
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y
Data variables:
    foo      (x, y) float64 55
```

Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like `col_names_values2['c731']` in your case is 1D even though you tell it to be a function of Time and Pres.

I can reproduce your error:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

coords = dict(
    Time=pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=11, freq="1d"),
    Pres=np.logspace(start=3, stop=0, base=10, num=5),
)

some_data = [
    33.12143542898356,
    33.12143542898356,
    33.12143542898356,
    33.12143542898356,
    33.12120589409984,
    33.18208891735566,
    33.12825967505915,
    33.12825967505915,
    33.12825967505915,
    33.12825967505915,
    33.12825967505915,
]

xr.Dataset(coords=coords, data_vars={"hehe": (("Time", "Pres"), some_data)})
```

This fails:

```
ValueError: Could not convert tuple of form (dims, data[, attrs, encoding]): (('Time', 'Pres'), [33.12143542898356, 33.12143542898356, 33.12143542898356, 33.12143542898356, 33.12120589409984, 33.18208891735566, 33.12825967505915, 33.12825967505915, 33.12825967505915, 33.12825967505915, 33.12825967505915]) to Variable.
```

However, passing actual 2D data works:

```
ntime = len(coords["Time"])
npres = len(coords["Pres"])
some_better_data = np.random.normal(size=(ntime, npres))

ds = xr.Dataset(coords=coords, data_vars={"hehe": (("Time", "Pres"), some_better_data)})
```

This yields the following `ds`:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (Time: 20, Pres: 5)
Coordinates:
  * Time     (Time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-20
  * Pres     (Pres) float64 1e+03 177.8 31.62 5.623 1.0
Data variables:
    hehe     (Time, Pres) float64 -1.053 -0.5254 0.6547 ... -0.6255 -0.2138
```

## Edit: if data is in fact 1D and is a function of `time` OR `pres`

then use this:

```
time = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=11, freq="1d")
pres = np.logspace(start=3, stop=0, base=10, num=11)

some_data = [
    33.12143542898356,
    33.12143542898356,
    33.12143542898356,
    33.12143542898356,
    33.12120589409984,
    33.18208891735566,
    33.12825967505915,
    33.12825967505915,
    33.12825967505915,
    33.12825967505915,
    33.12825967505915,
]

# option 1: make pressure a variable
res1 = xr.Dataset(
    coords={"time": time},
    data_vars={"hehe": ("time", some_data), "pres": ("time", pres)},
)
print(res1)
```

yields:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 11)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-11
Data variables:
    hehe     (time) float64 33.12 33.12 33.12 33.12 ... 33.13 33.13 33.13 33.13
    pres     (time) float64 1e+03 501.2 251.2 125.9 ... 7.943 3.981 1.995 1.0
```

or:

```
# option 2: make pressure an alternative coordinate to time
# this only works if pres is monotonic and there is a 1 to 1 mapping between time and pres

res2 = xr.Dataset(
    coords={"time": time, "pres": ("time", pres)},
    data_vars={"hehe": ("time", some_data)},
)
print(res2)
```

yields:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 11)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-11
    pres     (time) float64 1e+03 501.2 251.2 125.9 ... 7.943 3.981 1.995 1.0
Data variables:
    hehe     (time) float64 33.12 33.12 33.12 33.12 ... 33.13 33.13 33.13 33.13
```

then:

```
# for option 2: swap between time and pres
res2b = res2.swap_dims(time="pres")
print(res2b)
```

yields:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (pres: 11)
Coordinates:
    time     (pres) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-11
  * pres     (pres) float64 1e+03 501.2 251.2 125.9 ... 7.943 3.981 1.995 1.0
Data variables:
    hehe     (pres) float64 33.12 33.12 33.12 33.12 ... 33.13 33.13 33.13 33.13
```

Comment: And how do you keep the basic data? I'd like to not do np.random.normal because it takes the list at random, I'd like it to stay in the same order

Comment: Not sure if I fully get your question. How does your `col_names_values2['c731']` data look like? What shape does it have (1d or 2d)? You won't want to do `np.random.normal`, but you want `some_better_data` to be 2D –> it is function of `time` and `pres`

Comment: Its a list of 1d like that [324234, 12345] and time and pres are the same

Comment: What do you mean by "time and pres are the same"? Are they constant? So for every time and pres combination you want to store a 1D list? By using `"hehe": (("Time", "Pres"), ...` you specify 2 dimensions, therefore your data must be also 2D, not 1D.

Comment: Time and Pres are both different, and they are in a 1D list. The coords variable is in a dictionary. So in order for me to add them in dimensions I have to switch them to 2D? So I have to do that for all the data?

Comment: The coordinate vectors themselves are 1D, so I guess your variable `coords` should look fine. But you say that the variable `hehe` is a function of 2 dimensions, right? So the data that you try to assign to the variable `hehe` must also be 2D. But you are saying that  `col_names_values2['c731']` is 1D. This is where the error comes from I guess.

Comment: And how i can tranform that in a list 2D  ?

Comment: And the col_names_values2 is a dict()

Comment: Say `col_names_values2['c731']` is the data (abbreviated as "d") a function of p=[p1,p2] and t=[t1,t2]: d=d(p, t). xarray expects your data to look like this: [[d(p1, t1), d(p2, t1)], [d(p1, t2), d(p2, t2)]]. This is a 2D array. In what way is the 1D data `col_names_values2['c731']` corresponding to a 2D field?

Comment: I don't understand the question, how can i do it like that so ?

Comment: Please describe more in detail how `col_names_values2['c731']` describes your data as a function of time and pressure

Comment: The values in the `col_names_values2` list are measurements and I need to transform into a netCDF file. The data looks like this: `float64 38.92 38.92 38.92 38.92 ... 33.44 33.44 33.44`. The numbers are much larger but they are in a list 1 D

Comment: So to what time and pressure does the first, second, etc. value in the list correspond?

Comment: At all values. The samples were taken in milliseconds, so for each millisecond there is a sample of time and pressure. The time gives this value approximately: `(Time) int32 2300 2550 2800 ... 337800` and the pressure: `(Pres) float64 0.567 0.567 ... 0.26 `

Comment: Alright, we are getting there. Check out my edit above. `some_data` in your case is `col_names_values2['c731']`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you encounter is due to th fact the dimensions for the data variable "hehe" are not specified correctly. The dimensions should be specified as a tuple with the dimension names and their corresponding sizes, in the order that they appear in the data. In your case, the correct dimensions for "hehe" should be ("Time", "Pres").

I don't have your original data, so here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

time = np.arange(0, 365, 1)
time = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', periods=len(time), freq='D')

pressure = np.linspace(0, 1000, 20)
temperature = np.random.rand(len(time), len(pressure))
conductivity = np.random.rand(len(time), len(pressure))
salinity = np.random.rand(len(time), len(pressure))
chlorophyll = np.random.rand(len(time), len(pressure))

ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars={
        'temperature': (('time', 'pressure'), temperature),
        'conductivity': (('time', 'pressure'), conductivity),
        'salinity': (('time', 'pressure'), salinity),
        'chlorophyll': (('time', 'pressure'), chlorophyll),
    },
    coords={
        'time': time,
        'pressure': pressure,
    },
    attrs={
        'description': 'Example dataset for testing dimensions',
        'author': 'Your name',
    },
)
```

which produces

[image]

and you can drill down

[image]